# MassTransit - UsePartitioner - Multiple Consumers

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit, idempotent

We recently ran into an issue where users submit a request multiple times and because we're using the unit of work pattern inside of our consumers, those multiple requests would create duplicate records inside of our database.

We saw that there was a UsePartitioner method that we can add so that messages are partitioned on an ID that we set, and this would make the consumer wait until a message with that partitioned ID is done before starting on the next. This seems to work just fine locally with my docker setup where I'm only running one container per service. However, I noticed that when we deploy this to our other environments, we're still having that issue with duplicate records trying to be generated. I can't think of what else it could be unless maybe because our other environments have multiple containers/consumers running, that maybe the partitioning only happens on the single consumer and not shared? Or is there an additional setting that we're missing?

I should also add that we are using kubernetes. In our dev environment, we have 4 pods running so all 4 pods have an instance of this consumer.

[image]

```
    public class TestConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<TestConsumer>
    {
        public TestConsumerDefinition()
        {
            ConcurrentMessageLimit = 20;
        }

        protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
            IConsumerConfigurator<TestConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
        {
            var partitioner = consumerConfigurator.CreatePartitioner(ConcurrentMessageLimit.Value);

            consumerConfigurator.Message<TestMessage>(
                x =>
                    x.UsePartitioner(partitioner, m =>
                        $"{m.Message.DrugId}-{m.Message.PatientId}"));
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, there isn't a facility to partition across load balanced consumers on separate instances. You could build your own distributed lock, but...

The best approach would be to ensure your consumer logic is idempotent. Either using an upsert, or checking if the data already exists before adding it. Or, for extra credit, add the appropriate database-level constraint to prevent duplicates (either using a unique constraint or index).

The reason being, even a partitioner isn't going to prevent two requests a second apart from having the same data. So idempotent operations are important when dealing with distributed system.

Comment: Yes, we are doing a check to see if the data already exists before adding it. We've also added the database-level constraint. The issue is that we have one longer running consumer that does a bunch of different things. This longer running consumer doesn't need partitioning and they're allowed to process duplicate user messages. But it makes another call out to a different consumer (the one we've added partitioning on). This one will check to see if we have an existing record yet, and create one if it doesn't exist. Well if both messages come to this consumer at roughly the same time...

Comment: Then the second one will try to create it when the first one is already done, and will bomb out.

Comment: I guess I just assumed that by having an endpoint and multiple consumers on that endpoint, there was still a way to have configuration that is shared across those consumers. I didn't realize ConsumerDefinitions are actually only for the single consumer, and not shared across the pods in a kubernetes environment. There is an endpoint configurator inside of the consumer definition. I noticed in my example above that I was creating the partitioning on the consumer configurator, but in your docs, you're using endpoint configurator. Does that not make a difference either?

Comment: If that consumer is the only consumer configured on the endpoint, it doesn't make any difference.